# How to open a website using AutohotKey that contains special characters "%" in the url itself?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to open this website with this line of code:

```
Run,https://logowanie.uek.krakow.pl/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fe-uczelnia.uek.krakow.pl%2Flogin%2Findex.php%3FauthCAS%3DCAS
```

When i try to run this line I get this error:

```
The following variable name contains an illegal character:
'2Fe-uczelnia-uek.krakow.pl'
 
The program will exit.
```

Im pretty sure that "%" is the issue.

Comment: As far as I know the allowed characters for variable names are a to z, 0 to 9, #, _, @, $. That doesn't include space " " or period "." which is why it is throwing the error. 0x464e has the right of it, percent enclosed in quotes will not throw an error, same goes for a period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to encode URL while using Run command.

```
Run,https://logowanie.uek.krakow.pl/cas/login?service=https://e-uczelnia.uek.krakow.pl/login/index.php?authCAS=CAS
```

But if you really need or want to encode, you may try this function:

```
str := "hello%20world"
MsgBox, % decoded := EncodeDecodeURI(str, false)
MsgBox, % EncodeDecodeURI(decoded)

EncodeDecodeURI(str, encode := true, component := true) {
   static Doc, JS
   if !Doc {
      Doc := ComObjCreate("htmlfile")
      Doc.write("<meta http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"" content=""IE=9"">")
      JS := Doc.parentWindow
      ( Doc.documentMode < 9 && JS.execScript() )
   }
   Return JS[ (encode ? "en" : "de") . "codeURI" . (component ? "Component" : "") ](str)
}
```

Source: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=84825

Answer (score 2):

You want to ditch the usage of [legacy syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#legacy-syntax), and enter the modern [expression syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#expressions-vs-legacy-syntax) by specifying a single `%` at the start of that parameter.
Then you can explicitly specify a string with `""`:

```
Run, % "https://logowanie.uek.krakow.pl/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fe-uczelnia.uek.krakow.pl%2Flogin%2Findex.php%3FauthCAS%3DCAS"
```

---

If you for some reason were to want to use the legacy syntax, <sub><sup>(there is *no* valid reason to do so)</sup></sub>, you'd want to [escape](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/EscapeChar.htm) the `%`s with a `` ` ``.